# Is there a way to bypass / disable main thread check?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to disable / bypass Unity3D main thread check when accessing methods and fields from classes in UnityEngine and UnityEditor from other threads?

If so, what are the ways to achieve this?
Does anyone know how Unity Team have implemented this check?

(I know of, and am currently using other techniques that allow me to successfully resolve any multi-threading problems, but this question is of rather academic type :)

**Please respond only with possible solutions or informations why this cannot be done.**

Answer (score 0):

If Unity doesn't allow you to do something on the main thread respectively **not** on the main thread, assume there is at least one good reason for that.

Trying to circumvent it will almost inevitably result in problems, possibly hard to debug ones because Unity is trying to protect you from doing both outright illegal things that will corrupt or crash the app (ie accessing OpenGL context from a different thread) or things that are most likely going to lead to potential issues like race conditions, deadlocks, etc.

So even if there were a way to bypass said checks, without access to the code and profound understanding of multithreaded programming in the context of that code it would be highly counterproductive, self-defeating and setting yourself up for failures and hard to debug issues if you did actually manage to bypass said checks.

Every framework comes with a set of rules to work in. If Unity is saying "this method must be called on the main thread" you just follow those rules. Especially because you don't have access to the engine source code and could prove otherwise that in this specific set of circumstances it wouldn't be a problem. And if you had the source code, you could disable the check for those specific circumstances. Still, if the framework developer(s) insist that this wouldn't be a good idea you'll better listen to them because they surely know their framework far better than anyone else.

Comment: I know how that manipulating with this thread check can lead to issues, but that isn't answer to any of questions that were presented in this topic.

Comment: you asked why they implemented, this is as close to an answer as that question can be unless a Unity programmer is willing to disclose the information you seek. I strongly doubt there's any way to circumvent the checks, unless you were to hack unity's engine (likely violating the Unity ToS).

Comment: I seek other solutions, ones that do not break ToS and do not involve help from inside Unity - i.e. I thought about making Unity believe that other threads are the main thread.

Btw. I never asked why they implemented such restriction - if I were them I would probably do the same.